# Full Width Split Dropdown Button in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a place on my site which is using a bunch of `button` elements styled with `btn-block` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/TQSk6/1/) from the Twitter Bootstrap Docs).  I now want to switch some of them to split buttons ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/eBJGW/2/)), but I can't seem to get the split buttons and the normal buttons to be the same length.

I have experimented with all kinds of things, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.  Has anyone ever managed to do it?  Keep in mind that I do not want to hard-code the width of any elements if I don't have to. (Note that this includes not using hard-coded percentages either.)  If it is absolutely necessary, I am OK with defining a width for the toggle part of the button (because I know there will only be a single arrow character in there) but want to specify as few "magic numbers" as possible in order to keep the code maintainable in the future.

Comment: can you duplicate the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Eric Oops, I forgot to post that one. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/eBJGW/4/

Comment: link the bootstrap css as well

Comment: @Eric The Bootstrap CSS is linked in the "Manage Resources" tab on the side of the JSFiddle page.  It is the unmodified CSS from the Twitter Bootstrap demo site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the dropdown-lead in a container:

*(Note: This example is for Bootstrap 2.x)*

```css
.dropdown-lead {
  width: 100%;
}

.leadcontainer {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  width: 30px;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fillsplit {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button">Block level button</button>
<div class="btn-group btn-block fillsplit">
  <div class="leadcontainer">
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-lead" href="#"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> User</a>
  </div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> Ban</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="i"></i> Make admin</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
  </div>
```

Comment: sorry for taking so long to reply.  Yes, this does what I need.  I wish that there was a solution with nicer-looking code, but I doubt that's going to happen.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the same kind of behavior and found this flexbox solution: http://codepen.io/ibanez182/pen/MwZwJp

It's an elegant implementation which makes use of the `flex-grow` property.

Just add the `.btn-flex` class to the `.btn-group` in your HTML. This is all the CSS you need:

```
.btn-flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
}

.btn-flex .btn:first-child {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Credit goes to the author of the pen: [Nicola Pressi](http://codepen.io/ibanez182/)

Comment: I'll have to check this out. Flexbox was not yet supported widely enough in 2013 when I first asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the class btn-block to the .btn-group element and give the dropdownbutton elements % widths, that'd do the trick.

```
.dropdown-lead{
    width: 96%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropdown-toggle{
    width: 4%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/eBJGW/5/

Comment: This solution won't work for me.  The toggle button should be a constant size, not a small percentage - when you make the window narrower, it gets scroll bars because the arrow character is wider than the 4% box.  When you make the window wider, the 4% box is way too big.  I could get around this with responsive styles, but I'm really looking for a solution that works without having to fix the widths, or at a minimum to fix the width of the toggle and have the main button will the space.