# Bootstrap 3.0 - How do I make 2 buttons the same width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got two buttons.  One with the text that is very long, and the other with text that has a short length.

The default with BS is to vary the length of the button based on the length of the text.  My question is: how can I make them both the same length, irregardless of text length.

See my example here: http://bootply.com/110312

Thank you!

Comment: if you just want that button to be same length you can add style="width: 310px;" to the I wish I was that long button

Comment: or btn btn-success {width:xxpx;}

Comment: [I answered this for Bootstrap 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695985/full-width-split-dropdown-button-in-twitter-bootstrap) - hopefully it still applies for Bootstrap 3 - and then just wrap the whole thing in a div with a class like `col-md-4` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to test following code. Here the button-group will be expanded to the width of the parent element. If working please remove inline styles.

```
<div class="btn-group calendar-list-item" style="width:100%">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="width:88%">I am a very long button for all the world to see</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="btn-group calendar-list-item " style="width:100%">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:88%">I wish I was that long</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can use '.btn-block' class on buttons. this will expand button to the width of parent element. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050269/fixed-width-buttons-with-bootstrap)